# Unable to navigate between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using ListView with ViewHolder Implementation of CustomBaseAdapter. I am trying to move to another activity when an item is clicked on listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stubg
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NurseryRhymeDetailActivity.class);
                NurseryRhyme rhyme=(NurseryRhyme) parent.getItemAtPosition(1);

                intent.putExtra("title", rhyme.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", rhyme.getDescription());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

I am getting ActivityNotFoundException exception. How can this be solved?

The code for NurseryRhymeDetailActivity is as follows

```
public class NurseryRhymeDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("description");

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);


    }


}
```

Comment: please post the part of logcat that generates error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActivityNotFoundException`  have you declared this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

you must register the `NurseryRhymeDetailActivity` Activity into your `Manifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?